# Error ordenamiento datagridview en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me podrian ayudar para solucionar este error, me funciona en un `datagridview` normal, pero en este no me funciona, en este `datagridview` selecciono cualquier dato y me lo pone en el `texbox`.

**Funciona de esta manera para que me logren entender un poco mejor:**

[image: error]

Al seleccionar cualquier dato del datagridview me lo muestra en los `textbox`
pero al querer ordenar los datos ya sea por numero de factura o por nombre de cliente me marca el siguiente error, solo me funciona el ordenamiento por `ID`.

[image: error2]

El error me lo muestra en el codigo cuando selecciono cualquier dato del `datagridview` para mandarlo a los campos de `texbox` que pertenece 
este es el codigo:

```
 private void dataGridViewCatalogoPartes_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        txtId.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtnumfactura.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtCliente.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtparte.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        comboBoxTipoMaterial.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txtDescripcionEspañol.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        txtDescripcionIngles.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        txtCantidad.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        txtPrecioUnitario.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        txtpallet.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        txtobservaciones.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
        comboBoxPais.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
        txtpesopallet.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[13].Value.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Posiblemente porque la `Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[13]` no existe. Además, no estás usando `Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9]`.Revisa mejor el código. Usa bloques `try/catch` para controlar las excepciones.

Comment: es porque los `Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[13]` es la forma en que va enumerado los campos, por ejemplo el id pertenece al 0 y cuando lo seleciono los datos se ponen al textbox y el 9 no existe porquue es el total lo cual no hay ningun texbox donde agrego el total

Comment: Cuantas columnas tiene en total el `DataGridView`?

Comment: No entiendo que tiene que ver el orden con el click en las filas...

Comment: Lo mejor es que pongas un punto de interrupción en la primera línea del método dataGridViewCatalogoPartes_CellContentClick, una vez que se te pare el programa en el punto de interrupción, avanza paso a paso depurando para ver en que fila te da el error y nos lo dices

Comment: @Einer son 14 columnas y porque inclui una columna de mas que es cantidad * precio y el resultado lo pongo en una columna total por eso me brinco un numero

Comment: @gbianchi el orden es de acuerdo a los texbox, cuando doy click a un dato de los datagriedview estos datos se agregan a los textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas Daniel,

El problema que tienes es que al hacer click en el Filtro de la `DataGridView` se acciona el evento `CellContentClick` con el `Index = -1` y entonces te salta la excepción.

Deberías poner una condición para controlar que no te reaccione cuando le das click a una celda de Filtro:

```
private void dataGridViewCatalogoPartes_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        txtId.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtnumfactura.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtCliente.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtparte.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        comboBoxTipoMaterial.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txtDescripcionEspañol.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        txtDescripcionIngles.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        txtCantidad.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        txtPrecioUnitario.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        txtpallet.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        txtobservaciones.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
        comboBoxPais.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
        txtpesopallet.Text = this.dataGridViewCatalogoPartes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[13].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```